# Cant target value in Dictionary Node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies

```
const j = require('request').jar();
const request = require('request').defaults({
  jar: j
});

request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: "https://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=csi&ei=_-34WouCCoaWsgWUsLfoBQ&s=newtab&adh=&conn=onchange&ima=1&ime=0&imeb=0&imeo=0&mem=ujhs.10,tjhs.10,jhsl.2190&rt=aft.13,ol.20,prt.14,xjs.317,xjsee.317,xjses.230,xjsls.37,wsrt.95,cst.0,dnst.0,rqst.18,rspt.10,rqstt.27,unt.25,cstt.25,dit.111&zx=1526264059738"
}, function(err, res, body) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(j._jar.cookies));
```

this gives:

> undefined

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(j));
```

this gives:

> {"_jar":{"version":"tough-cookie@2.3.3","storeType":"MemoryCookieStore","rejectPublicSuffixes":true,"cookies":[{"key":"NID","value":"130=F2nMvgnjWwGNndAE7c0rlU8AIgvX-EsDL-qc_kFLT18upWh87niN-_Th5oMbUyDe7LV5HWNVcsUKb6SUwQuC6VTWgC-jnPmHo4tLnFPb8r7p3CEbMN7MYxAFpucRfl8o","expires":"2018-11-13T03:50:35.000Z","domain":"google.com","path":"/","httpOnly":true,"hostOnly":false,"creation":"2018-05-14T03:50:35.944Z","lastAccessed":"2018-05-14T03:50:35.944Z"}]}}

```
});
```

I need the cookies:[] as shown in the output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j` is an instance of `RequestJar` Object while `j._jar` is an instance of `CookieJar` Object. `CookieJar(_jar)` does not have `cookies` field but you can access `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j._jar)).cookies`

```
request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: "https://www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=csi&ei=_-34WouCCoaWsgWUsLfoBQ&s=newtab&adh=&conn=onchange&ima=1&ime=0&imeb=0&imeo=0&mem=ujhs.10,tjhs.10,jhsl.2190&rt=aft.13,ol.20,prt.14,xjs.317,xjsee.317,xjses.230,xjsls.37,wsrt.95,cst.0,dnst.0,rqst.18,rspt.10,rqstt.27,unt.25,cstt.25,dit.111&zx=1526264059738"
}, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j._jar)).cookies);
  });
```